# Comparing models Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model

I have one model call Permissions of about 60 columns where half of the column represents a boolean and half of them a text (:string) field.

I would like to be able to compare 2 different objects of this model.

The comparison will be able to present **ONLY** the **True** values of the 1st Object compared with the equivalent columns in the other object. **Forget about the values containing or not text!**

For example:

**Object 1:**

```
Permission:
    Read_disk :true
    Write_disk :true
    Modify_disk :true
    Delete_disk :true
    Every other permission FALSE or TEXT so I do not care about them.
```

**Object 2:**

```
Permission:
    Read_disk :false     (*I care about that because it was true in object 1)
    Write_disk :false    (*I care about that because it was true in object 1)
    Modify_disk :true    (*I care about that because it was true in object 1)
    Delete_disk :true    (*I care about that because it was true in object 1)
    Every other might be TRUE or FALSE or TEXT but I do not care about them because those permissions were false in the object 1
```

In my view I would like to present this comparison showing only the true columns of **Object 1** and the equivalent fields of **Object 2**

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Permissions < ActiveRecord::Base
  def compare(permission)
    true_attributes = self.attributes.select{|k, v| v==true }
    equivalent_attributes = permission.attributes.select{|k, v| true_attributes.key?(k) }

    [true_attributes, equivalent_attributes]
  end
end

object_1_permissions, object_2_permissions = object_1.compare(object_2)
```

Comment: But at the end I want to return 2 objects. One object with the true values of Object 1. And another one with ONLY the equivalent values to the true values from Object 2..

Comment: That's what this does. `object_1_permissions` now has the true attributes from Object 1, `object_2_permissions` now has it's values for the same attributes.

Comment: You are kidding:p `object_1_permissions, object_2_permissions = object_1.compare(object_2)` Does this line do all the magic? Can you explain it a bit please?? Because I am new to Rails?

Comment: This is where object_1 and 2 are instances of the Permissions class defined above (which I'm assuming is a ruby on rails model). The work happens in the Permissions#compare method.

Comment: Mate thanks a lot. Seriously. One last question: Is `[true_attributes, equivalent_attributes]` a return statement and `object_1_permissions, object_2_permissions = object_1.compare(object_2)` a method call ?

Comment: Yes, it's a clever thing you can do in ruby. Try `a, b, c = [1, 2, 3]` - c now equals 3, a is 1 etc.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to be able to find records of your Object in relation to another record.  This isn't too hard

```
obj = Object.find(some_id)
conditions = Hash.new
obj.attributes.each do |key, value|
    if value == true
        conditions[key] = value
    end
end
interestingObjects = Object.where(conditions).all
```

And then your `interestingObjects` will have the records you want!

Comment: Thanks mate. I think this is correct.. My previous comment: I do not care about false attributes of object 1. Only true. In addition I do not care if the attribute in Object 1 is the same with the attribute in Object 2. I only care about true attributes from Object 1. And returning 2 object. 1st Object will be ONLY the true attributes from Object 1. Object 2 will be the equivalent to true values of object 1